# Is there a component that can record circuit on-time without a battery?

Tags: timer

I don't know if such a thing exists already. I'm looking for a component that can record how long a circuit has been powered on. Kind of like the "change filter" light on a fancy vacuum cleaner. It must be able to resume recording after being powered off and on again and cannot use a battery backup.

I've already implemented this before using a microcontroller and FRAM, but i'm curious if such a thing already exists on the market in one package.

edit: the component must also be resettable.

Comment: Some of them could "record" the amount of "heat" delivered to a house radiator ... And it is a function of temperature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Curtis Instruments [Solid State Elapsed Time Monitor 200 SERIES](https://cdn.curtisinstruments.com/products/datasheets/200_datasheet_en.pdf) description contains:

> Safe, reliable EEPROM memory storage of data **without battery back up**

The datasheet linked above shows the data format used to read the elapsed time:
[image]

Some models have a pin which can reset the elapsed time. It looks like there is some protection against inadvertent reset of the elapsed time since:

1. The supply voltage range is 4.75 – 10 VDC
2. The reset voltage is 20 VDC +/– 5%, supplied on a dedicated pin.

This was just the first example of a Solid State Elapsed Time Monitor I found where the datasheet described how the elapsed time was recorded in non-volatile memory (in this example EEPROM).

Comment: Wow... So I essentially just designed one of these from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of [elapsed-time meters](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/elapsed-time-meters/) that you can just purchase off of McMaster; these use a small motor that spins whenever powered on to drive a mechanical counter mechanism, much like the odometer on a car.

There's another type, no longer in common use (as it relies upon the toxic heavy metal mercury) but which I personally find fascinating, called a [mercury coulometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_coulometer).

[image]
([image source](https://www.reddit.com/r/ElectricalEngineering/comments/eeczu1/electrochemical_hour_meter_a_drop_of_electrolyte/))

These work by using the predictable rate of electromigration of a droplet of mercury in a tube full of electrolyte (or a droplet of electrolyte in a tube full of mercury) when a known current is passed through it. These were used extensively in the past (I know several Tektronix instruments used them), but they are now rare and nigh-impossible to get due to regulations and the availability of better modern solutions.

Comment: Is it Chronistor?

Comment: @GodJihyo I had actually never heard of that type! I was thinking of mercury coulometers.

Comment: the Chronistors used copper, so no mercury to worry about, but I doubt they're still made.

Comment: Is it possible to reset one of those elapsed time meters?

Comment: @BobaJFET The [Mercury coulometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_coulometer#Construction) Wikipedia page says ``If the direction of the current is changed, the drop moves in the opposite direction``. Not sure what amount of reverse current would be needed to reset a Mercury coulometer in a reasonable duration.

Comment: The datasheet I linked shows a 100 hour minimum time when passing maximum current (85uA) through the device. That's 1/100 of the maximum full scale 10,000 hours.  So it would be fully reset in at most about 4 days of 24/7 reverse operation @ maximum current.

Answer (score 1):

There are electromechanical run time meters, used on generators and such like. If memory serves, some even operate without power connections, using vibration to actuate the mechanism (purely mechanical, no 'electro').

There are (or were) also electrochemical devices. I have a Tektronix oscilloscope that has [such a component](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/repair/found-some-strange-part-in-a-tektronix-2336-and-would-like-to-know-more-about/?action=dlattach;attach=985812) internally to indicate roughly to total time the instrument has been powered. The 'scope dates from the late 1960's I think.

[image]

It contains mercury so it would be frowned upon, if not outright prohibited, today.

And, as mentioned by @ vir there are also [single-chip fully electronic devices](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/DS1682.pdf) that contain an oscillator and non-volatile memory. The linked one is accurate to a couple percent and is write-protected to prevent unauthorized reset (they don't seem to have a unique serial number factory-assigned, but there is some internal user EEPROM that could be pressed into service ).

[image]

Comment: This device might best be described as "electrochemical". As a bonus, these can be reset!

Comment: @gbarry Yes, electrochemical, perfect, I'll add that. I'm not sure the reset ability is a bonus when applied to warranty period for devices aimed at  engineering types, but in those days word traveled slowly.

Answer (score 1):

Analog and Maxim (and probably more manufacturers) make resettable elapsed-time recorder chips that have their own compensated RTC and non-volatile memory so you can poll the amount of time it's been powered through I2C.  Some also track edge transitions on a separate event pin if that's useful for you.